# Can one graphic card support 2 QHD displays?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Could a graphics card like R9 280x run two QHD displays? Currently I have two monitors (QHD + FullHD) and its running without any issues.

My graphics card currently has DVI, HDMI and DisplayPort outputs. Currently using 1x Dual link DVI for the QHD DVI a 1x HDMI for FullHD display. Can I use the display port for new QHD? Could it teoretically support 3 monitors - QHD,QHD,FullHD?

There seem to be lack of information on this topic on the Internet (or I am searching wrong). Found a couple of forums where they say you need 2 cards and crossfire them, but I find that quite unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

There is a maximum number of pixels that any given GPU is capable of pushing.

QHD is 2560x1440, which equals 3,686,400 pixels. Twice that is 7,372,800. So you're looking for a graphics card that can push 7,372,800 pixels per screen refresh cycle, or either 2560x2880 or 5120x1440 maximum resolution

Some cards will note the raw pixel numbers, others the resolution numbers, and it appears there are several cards that do this today:

For instance, the nVidia Titan X has a maximum resolution of 5160x3200 on digital outputs. This is well more than dual-QHD.

*NOTE: QHD is NOT the same thing as 4K. QHD is 4 times 720 vertical pixels. 4K is 4 times 1080 vertical pixels.*

Comment: Thank you, yes Im talking about QHD, not 4k. Just to confirm, I always thought when graphic cards says it has maximum resolution 2560x1440 it does not necessarily mean it will not be able to push this resolution two times to two different displays. Or am I wrong?

Comment: When a graphics card says it has a maximum resolution, that is the maximum number of pixels it can push, period. So, that number plus the outputs the card has tells you how many and what resolution screens you can connect. If you connected one theoretical 5160x3200 pixel monitor to the nVidia Titan X and ran it at full resolution, even though there are more connectors available on the card, you would not be able to run a monitor on them.